# How can I execute my custom scripts without typing bash before?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to run my custom scripts but every time I need to execute it I have to type bash before the script name. But I want to run it just like we would run other scripts such as `ls git sed chmod` etc where typing bash prior to the script name is not required.

I haven't found any solution here, but the closest was this [Bash Script does nothing](https://superuser.com/questions/633149/bash-script-does-nothing)

I have created a script named `test`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello
```

But when I type it on terminal it gives no error and prints nothing

```
user@notebook:~$ test
user@notebook:~$
```

But it works when I type it with bash

```
user@notebook:~$ bash test
Hello
user@notebook:~$
```

I have added the file to `~/.local/bin/`, given it the permission `chmod a+x test` and `~/.local/bin` is set in my `PATH` variable.

---

My `stat /bin/bash` is

```
  File: /bin/bash
  Size: 1396520     Blocks: 2728       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 30408799    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-05-07 12:23:17.179593764 +0500
Modify: 2022-01-06 21:23:33.000000000 +0500
Change: 2022-10-08 20:47:19.225627603 +0500
Birth: 2022-10-08 20:47:19.217622335 +0500
```

My `stat /bin` is

```
  File: /bin -> usr/bin
  Size: 7           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 12          Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-05-07 12:22:43.299594371 +0500
Modify: 2022-10-08 20:47:18.020812502 +0500
Change: 2022-10-08 20:47:18.020812502 +0500
Birth: 2022-10-08 20:47:18.020812502 +0500
```

The output of `type -a test` is:

```
test is a shell builtin 
test is /home/saad/.local/bin/test 
test is /usr/bin/test 
test is /bin/test
```

Comment: Is Bash actually installed in `/bin/bash`? Please include output of `stat /bin/bash` and `stat /bin`. Also, which version of Ubuntu are you using? Thanks.

Comment: i used `which bash` and it returned `/usr/bin/bash`. I have corrected that but still there is no change for me. My ubuntu version is `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`. I have added the `stat` output in my question.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an alias or shell function that is masking the script? What is the output of `type -a myscript`?

Comment: The prompt says that you create your script in your HOME directory: `user@notebook:~$ bash myscript` What is the output of `readlink -f myscript` ?

Comment: @steeldriver I haven't touched my alias since the installation. The output of `type -a myscript` 'is myscript is a shell builtin
myscript is /home/saad/.local/bin/myscript
myscript is /usr/bin/myscript
myscript is /bin/myscript'

Comment: @GillesQuénot the output to `readlink -f myscript` is `/home/saad/.local/bin/myscript`

Comment: So right there `myscript is a shell builtin` (presumably your script isn't actually called `myscript`, but is named the same as one of the [Shell Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Builtin-Index.html) ?

Comment: Ok call your scriptfile something else, and try again.

Comment: If your scriptfile is called `test` or `echo`, please edit your question accordingly for clarity.

Comment: I guess the script is named after its contents: `echo` ... hence `/bin/echo` and `/usr/bin/echo` the external echo command ... Bash also has a builtin `echo` ... Had you used the actual script-file's name, it would've been a lot easier for you and us :-)

Comment: I'm leaning more towards `echo` now that you mention it! 

Comment: It was my mistake that I used a placeholder, I have updated the question to match my problem. Thank you guys!

Comment: `test.sh` would have been sufficient to avoid this pitfalls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gives away what has really happened:

> The output of `type -a test` is:
>
> ```
> test is a shell builtin 
> test is /home/saad/.local/bin/test
> test is /usr/bin/test
> test is /bin/test
> ```

1. Your script has the name `test`, which is the same as a [Builtin Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Builtin-Index.html)
2. *NEVER* name your scripts exactly the same as internal commands - this will have unwanted consequences.
3. So you simply need to name your scriptfile *something else* than `test` (or any other internal command).
4. If you want to run your own script *instead* of a standard application (like `ls`), you should create an alias with the name and the full path of your script, like:

   ```
   alias ls='/home/saad/.local/bin/myscript'
   ```

###### *Important note:*

The next time you ask a question like this, please include the *correct* name of your script, and not a *placeholder* name. Now that you have included the correct name, it's obvious to many of the users here that it was called `test`, which is the same as an internal command.

Comment: Thank you and the others who commented. It was my mistake that I used a place holder which lengthened the time to answer here. I appreciate you guys!